# Использование объекта в if

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не получается правильно использовать `if`, или же ошибка совсем в другом.

Скрипт считает сумму заказанных услуг:

1. Выбирается день и уровень из `<select>`'ов `#days` и `#lvl`. Сумма записывается в переменную `up`.
2. На календаре выбираются числа для рекламы, записываются в `<input>` `#altField`. Также подсчитывается количество дней, которое записывается в переменную `reklama`.

вот я вставил весь код чтоб увидели как работает http://jsfiddle.net/8o28p0hy выберите на пример уровень 1 и дни 2. должно посчитать 0.6, а считает 1.2 но когда значение появляется в инпуте реклама, даже при клике в инпут, то сумма уже становится правильной - 0.6

для ясности, инпут реклама считает значения введенные через запятую с пробелом.

Comment: покажите код dayCount. на всякий случай - он скорее всего возвращает строку, а не число. а строка == true

Comment: function dayCount( val ){
         try {
             return {
                 days: val.match(/\S+/g).length
             }
         }
         catch (ex) {
             return {
                 days:0
             };
         }
     }

Comment: так в чем именно проблема? вы возвращаете ненулевой объект c. if (c) всегда true. что именно не работает?

Comment: вот и проблема что у меня получается с всегда тру и тогда даже если days и lvl не заполнены, мне все равно что то считает...

Comment: потому что if не знает, что нужно проверять c.days. он проверять что c != null. если нужно проверять c.days - так и напишите - `if (c.days)`

Comment: я так уже пробовал. не помогало... то же самое...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `dayCount` у вас вседа возвращает ненулевой объект - или количество дней, или заглушку `{ days: 0 }`.

`if` воспринимает ненулевой объект как `true'. Если вы хотите проверять на ненулевое количество дней - замените на

```
if (c.days) {
```

или на

```
if (c.days > 0) {
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось...

Comment: вот я вставил весь код чтоб увидели как работает https://jsfiddle.net/8o28p0hy/ выберите на пример уровень 1 и дни 2. должно посчитать 0.6, а считает 1.2 но когда значение появляется в инпуте реклама, даже при клике в инпут, то сумма уже становится правильной - 0.6

Comment: @akasergej вы код наугад пишете?  в обработчике this - это елемент, на котором произошло событие. вы в самом начале обработчика берете значение `this.value`. когда вы выбираете значение из дропдауна - this - это дропдаун. и приходит 1 день. когда вы кликаете на инпут - this - это инпут. this.value - уже значение инпута - пустое - 0 дней. естественно, у вас получается разный результат.

Comment: да, в общем то наугад. слепливал два по отдельности рабочих кода в один и так как в javascripte не силен получается такая каша. не могли бы вы поправить как нужно правильно?

Comment: @akasergej замените `this.value` на `$("#idтогоэлементаизкоторогонужновзятьзначение").val()`. какого именно - вам лучше знать )

Comment: о счастье! вы меня спасли )) понимал, что так и нужно, но не зная синтаксиса писал $("#altField").val() без скобочек () после .val Теперь все работает как надо. спасибо! :)